# Getting "ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number" in DeleteCommand of SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net, oracle, gridview, sqldatasource, sql-delete

I have a **GridView**. It's connected to a **SqlDataSource**. My database is **Oracle**.

When I run the webpage, **SELECT** command works and I see the items in the list. When I click **Delete** button, I get this error:

> ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Here is my GridView and SqlDataSource:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="ajaxMyLinks" runat="server" width="100%" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
     <telerik:RadGrid ID="gridMyLinks" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceMyLinks" AllowAutomaticDeletes="True" AllowPaging="True" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" PageSize="5" ShowHeader="False">
         <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceMyLinks" DataKeyNames="N_USER_LINK_ID">
             <Columns>
                 <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn AllowSorting="False" DataNavigateUrlFields="V_LINK" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="{0}" DataTextField="V_LINK_TITLE" DataTextFormatString="{0}" FilterControlAltText="Filter column column" UniqueName="column" Target="_blank">
                 </telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn>
                 <telerik:GridButtonColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="Content/images/delete.png" UniqueName="column1">
                 </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
             </Columns>
         </MasterTableView>
         <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrev" ShowPagerText="False" />
     </telerik:RadGrid>
 </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceMyLinks" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT V_LINK_TITLE, V_LINK, N_USER_LINK_ID FROM TAPP_IFH_USER_LINK WHERE (N_USER_ID = :USER_ID) ORDER BY N_USER_LINK_ID DESC" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM TAPP_IFH_USER_LINK WHERE (N_USER_LINK_ID = :USER_LINK_ID)" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection.ProviderName %>">
  <DeleteParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="USER_LINK_ID" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
  </DeleteParameters>
  <SelectParameters>
      <asp:SessionParameter Name="USER_ID" SessionField="USER_ID" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. **Parameter names were not matching** between column name in DB and parameter. Parameter name was **USER_LINK_ID** while column name was **N_USER_LINK_ID**.

If this is not the problem in your case, check [this post](http://sirusbasevi.webs.com/apps/blog/show/5071641-the-ora-01036-illegal-variable-name-number-error-with-asp-net-3-5) out. It has more suggestions